# run oncomplete event in async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Is there someway of letting an oncomplete event run in Async. The oncomplete event is called from an external dll. The external dll uses Async and I am creating a wrapper for it that hides multithreading.

I Have tried using AutoResetEvents but these get stuck on the WaitOne as the oncomplete event which resets the AutoResetEvent only runs after the function is completed.

From what I can pickup from the external Dll, the object tree needs to be synced to the main form in order to function. This forces everything on a single thread. GetTag is called as GetTag(this).

```
protected EventWaitHandle SyncEvent;
public string GetTag(object syncObject)
    {
        string lResult = "";
        SyncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        XiServer lOPCServer = new XiServer(OPCServer.ServerID, OPCServer.ApplicationName, syncObject); //create local instance of server synced to mainform
        lOPCServer.Initiate(OnInitiated2, null); //Connect server
        SyncEvent.WaitOne(); //Wait here for for connect to finish, Freezes here

        if  (ServerTree == null)
            ServerTree = new ObjectTree(lOPCServer, lOPCServer.ServerInfo.ServerName);
        DialogResult dlr = ServerTree.ShowDialog();
        if (dlr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lResult =  ServerTree.SelectedObject.InstanceId.FullyQualifiedId;
        }
        lOPCServer.Dispose();
        return lResult;
    }
private void OnInitiated2(Exception aError, object asyncState)
    {
        if (aError != null)
        {
            GlobalException = aError;
        }
        SyncEvent.Set();            
    }
```

So in short, is there someway I can let the code wait till after the Initiate was finsihed? I dont have access to the initiate code.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own event / delegate?

Comment: The delegate, the function calls, is embedded in the dll. Are you proposing a create some kind of wrapper delegate?

Comment: If a call to LOPCServer.Initiate does not block, you could move the remaining logic to OnInitiated2 callback (I guess).
That is everything below a call to Initiate goes to the callback function.

Comment: lOPCServer.Initiate does not block, thats essentially the problem. I want it to. But the problem with added the remaining logic in the callback is how do I get my return value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I found away around this. 
I keep checking a field that should be set last on on the initiate function. 
On the server object I am using the isConnected field

```
while ((lOPCServer.IsConnected == false) && (lTimeout < 60000)) //1 min timeout
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    lTimeout += 10;
}

if (lTimeout >= 60000)
{
    return ""; //Server initaite timed out
}
```

Comment: What if the separate two threads calls the `GetTag` simultaneously? Your server will be initiated twice.

Comment: I dont think I understand exactly what your saying. But if I understand correctly. It does not matter if GetTag is called twice from two separate threads. The variables it uses are all local and the server can handle many concurrent connections ( GetTag already creates a temporarily second connection to the server)

Comment: Ok then, just clarifying